# Test fails locally, but not on server

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tfs, simple-injector

We have the following unit test on our WebAPI project:

```
[TestMethod]
[TestCategory("UnitTests.InternalAPi")]
[TestCategory("ContainerConfigTests")]
[TestCategory("ContainerConfigTests.RegisterComponents")]
public void ContainerVerified()
{
    // HACK: This isn't really a unit test per se, it's testing components that we're not 
    // directly interested in. However, it exists to provide an early warning that the 
    // container config would fail at runtime.

    var container = new Container();

    ContainerConfig.RegisterApplicationComponents(container);

    container.Verify();

    // An Exception will be thrown if the container does not verify correctly.
    Assert.IsTrue(true); 
}
```

The purpose of this test, is that it performs the DI registrations that the API does (or all the classes we created, at least - it skips the Controller registrations, etc), then verifies that everything works correctly.

If a registration is missing, this test will fail as expected on the local VS instance (it throws an exception, causing the test to fail). However, it doesn't fail on the server.

The output from the TestResult file on TFS indicates that this test did run, and that it passed.

What could be causing this issue?

---

**Update**

The actual setup of this solution is a little complicated, due to some of our internal requirements, but a description of this setup is below:

- Solution 1

  - Core Project

    - Contains Interface to register
  - Implementation Project

    - Contains Interface Implementation
    - Project Ref to Core
- Solution 2

  - Core Project

    - Contains Interface to register
  - API Project

    - Project Ref to Core
    - Dll ref to Implementation
  - Test Project

    - Project Ref to Core
    - Project Ref to API
    - Dll Ref to Implementation

**API Method**

```
public class ContainerConfig
{
  public static void RegisterApplicationComponents(Container container)
  {
    container.Register<ICoreInterface, Implementation.Implementation>();
  }
}
```

**Steps to Reproduce**

1. Open Solution 2
2. Update Core Interface with new method
3. Build Solution 2
4. Run Verify Unit Test
5. Verify fails locally

> Test Name:    ContainerVerified
>   Test FullName:  UnitTests.UnitTest1.ContainerVerified
>   Test Source:    d:\Users\freilly\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\WebApi\UnitTests\UnitTest1.cs : line 16
>   Test Outcome:   Failed
>   Test Duration:  0:00:00.0951898
>
> Result StackTrace: 
>   at WebApi.App_Start.ContainerConfig.RegisterApplicationComponents(Container container)
>      at UnitTests.UnitTest1.ContainerVerified() in d:\Users\freilly\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\WebApi\UnitTests\UnitTest1.cs:line 23
>   Result Message: 
>   Test method UnitTests.UnitTest1.ContainerVerified threw exception: 
>   System.TypeLoadException: Method 'TestFailureMethod' in type 'Implementation.Implementation' from assembly 'Implementation, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.

6. Commit Changes - Test passes on CI build

Comment: could it be that there are certain assemblies only available server side? These assemblies could contain types that some batch register method would pick up causing the object graph to be complete.

Comment: Possible, but unlikely in this case I think, the issue locally is a dll (we control) has a mismatch in the interface between whats expected and what it implements. Trying to gather more info to see if I can narrow down the scenario (I thought I had a solution to the issue, but it didn't work out)

Comment: It's impossible to say anything about this without seeing your configuration and the reason that it fails locally. Can you show us the local exception?

Comment: Here are some pointers: are you using a different version of Simple Injector on the build server? Are you loading types using reflection, for instance by supplying a dynamic list of assemblies using `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` to one of Simple Injector's `RegisterXXX` overloads?

Comment: @Steven we are using reflection to do the registrations. I'll update the question with a description of the setup in place, but it's a little complicated - may see if I can get a demo solution that might help.

Comment: Why does the test fail locally? With what error?

Comment: @Steven sorry, meant to add that. It just says that the interface method doesn't have an implementation - pretty much what you'd expect really.

Comment: Can you add the stack trace? This is not an error that is thrown by Simple Injector.

Comment: @Steven Updated. Also added the solutions here: http://tinyurl.com/po8oow8 - don't want to add it to the question though, as I may remove it later.

As far as I can see, the test absolutely *should* be failing. And it does locally, which is fine. But it passes on the server CI build.

Comment: Can you post all inner exception details (stack traces and messages) as well?

Comment: @Steven thats all the test spits out.

Comment: There is more information. You will have to get that. Without this information you can't anything. You have to know what causes this exception locally.